# Hammer.js on tap is stoppng parent div from scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hammer.js

I am currently using Hammer.JS to create a desktop and mobile friendly user interface.

The following is the CSS for a parent div that has smaller divs in it populated by JS.

```
.attributescroll {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #1A1A1A;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

It is populated by several child elements as ".attribute"

For each of them, I have a tap event tied which set text elsewhere in the text (for now). But in doing so I now cannot scroll the parent div.

```
$('.attribute').each(function() {
  var selectedAttribute = new Hammer(this);
  selectedAttribute.on("tap", function(event) {
    if ($(".mobiletopicwrap").css("display") == "block") {
      $(".mtopmytopic").html($(event.target).html());
    } else {
      $(".topmytopic").html($(event.target).html());
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried setting touch-action but to no avail. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: This answer might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198150/hammerjs-swipe-not-working-on-elements-with-overflow-css-property

Comment: Thank you @RinoTovar, this is a 3 year old question and I haven't used HammerJS in a while since then but thank you for taking the time for future viewers to perhaps solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't reproduce your situation.
Based on your code, I wrote this code snippet below. Hope you can reproduce your issue in a similar way hence I could provide further help with it.

```js
$('.attribute').each(function() {
  var selectedAttribute = new Hammer(this);
  selectedAttribute.on("tap", function(event) {
    if ($(".mobiletopicwrap").css("display") == "block") {
      $(".mtopmytopic").html($(event.target).html());
    } else {
      $(".topmytopic").html($(event.target).html());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.attributescroll {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #1A1A1A;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.attribute {
  width: 100px;
  background: darkred;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.parent {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>

<div class="attributescroll">
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
  <div class="attribute"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, from what I can tell the error is still happening with this code too. It is worth mentioning that this only happens in mobile. I have actually brought it down to something in mobile Chrome and how it uses hammer.js. I borrowed a friends phone and used Safari and it worked. I have submitted an issue to hammer.js. Thank you for your time and effort in trying to replicate and fix the problem.